Is there a "weak" fundamental theorem of algebra for matrices?
Let $R$ be the ring of complex $n\times n$ matrices, where $n>1$.
Does every nonconstant polynomial in $R[X]$ have a root in $R$?
Note: The "strong" fundamental theorem of algebra for matrices fails, see here.
As far as I can see the "weak" fundamental theorem of algebra would not imply the "strong" fundamental theorem of algebra, due to noncommutativity.

In your linked question, a commenter points out the existence of a $2\times 2$ matrix $N$ which is not a square. The example given is $N = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$: if $N$ had a square root $\sqrt{N}$, then $N$ and $\sqrt{N}$ would commute; but the commutator of $N$ are the matrices of the form $a + Nb$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, and $(a + Nb)^2 = a^2 + 2ab N \neq 0 + 1N$. For this matrix $N$, $x^2 - N$ does not have a root.

@TheoJohnson-Freyd: it's even simpler than that :-), see my answer below.

Perhaps @TheoJohnson-Freyd's example is a little more satisfying because the polynomial is monic. (Although I would say centraliser instead of commutator, which to me has a different meaning.)

@LSpice: I agree! His example does not rely on the cheap commutative algebra characterization of invertible polynomials I used :-)

@M.G. I was also trying to point out that the answer was already available in the OP's source material...

Would a "polynomial" be something whose terms look like $A_1XA_2XA_3XA_4\cdots A_{k-1} X A_k$?

@MichaelHardy: OP's notation usually means that the indeterminate commutes with the coefficients. What you are thinking of is the free product of rings $R \ast \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

@M.G. Do you mean that in this case the coefficients of the polynomial are scalars?

@MichaelHardy: If you mean OP's case, then no, the coefficients are definitely not scalars, they are from $R$, but the indeterminate is assumed to behave like a scalar. And yes, it's ambigious how one inserts the matrix in the place of the variable, except in my example :-)

@MichaelHardy: And, yes, OP should have used the free product instead to avoid such ambiguity or at least specified a substitution convention, but in the end it didn't matter.

Usually polynomials are written $A_0+A_1X+A_2X^2+...$ I don't think it is very ambiguous how to insert a matrix into it...

@ResearchMath: Yes (and that's what me and probably everyone else presumed you meant), but that notation/convention implicitly assumes that the indeterminate $X$ commutes with the (non-commutative) coefficients. More precisely, polynomial rings are defined via Cauchy Products, so evaluation of $X$, especially at a non-commutative point, is sort of additional structure on top of that. For example, what if instead we wanted to calculate $A_0 + Y A_1 + Y^2 A_2 + \dots$ for $Y \in R$? As a polynomial, this would be the same as yours.

We don't require any ring structure on the polynomials for this question. I don't agree that "that notation/convention implicitly assumes that the indeterminate $X$
commutes with the (non-commutative) coefficients."

@ResearchMath: I don't claim that we need the ring structure of $R[X]$ for this question, I am simply stating what the notation means and why there is no canonical way to substitute with a non-commutative element, hence the need to specify the action. Looking at $R[X]$ only as an $R$-module does not resolve the problem - in theory one still needs to specify if the action is left or right. Whether you agree or not with my sentence about $X$ commuting with the coefficients is irrelevant since this is a direct consequence of the definition. (cont.)

@ResearchMath: (cont.) BTW, When $R$ is explicitly said to be a ring, then $R[X]$ is usually understood with its inherited ring structure (otherwise why specify $R$ to be a ring?). If you only take $R[X]$ as an $R$-module, then you should either say so explicitly or say that $R$ is the module of $n \times n$ matrices.

The previous remark is of course assuming that the action is "consistently oriented" for each summand. Of course, one can have a right action on the first coefficient, a left action on the second and so on.

You say "then $R[X]$ is usually understood with its inherited ring structure", this is an assumption on your part. So you are willing to assume this, but you are not willing to assume that polynomials be written $A_0+A_1X+A_2X^2+...$ and substituted in the obvious way (since I didn't specify otherwise). I actually have no problem viewing $R[X]$ as a set.

@ResearchMath: There is a difference. By "usually" above, I really mean "always" - it's the definition of the object/notation $R[X]$ when $R$ is a ring. It's not an assumption, it's a universally accepted notation/convention. Thus, when you mean something else by $R[X]$, for example its module structure only, it's best you specify this explicitly. As for the obvious substitution, I (and probably others) did assume it exactly that way (see answer). But that's also the point - it's an assumption, not a convention, it's not canonical, nor it's implied by the definition of $R[X]$.

No, for rather trivial reasons. Consider the polynomial $f(X) = \varepsilon X - 1$ with $\varepsilon^2 = 0$, $\varepsilon \neq 0$, in $R = M_2(\mathbb{C})$. Then a root of $f(X)$ would mean that $\varepsilon$ is invertible in $R$, which is of course impossible. Alternatively, just take $\det$ on both sides.

Although what you are asking for is not true, there is a very interesting related fact that is true. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of any characteristic. The theory of matrix factorisations shows that every homogeneous polynomial in $R=k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ factorises in a suitable matrix ring $\operatorname{Mat}_s(R)$ as a product of linear factors. This follows from Theorem 1.2 of Herzog, Ulrich and Backelin, "Linear maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules over strict complete intersections" (see also Backelin, Herzog and Sanders, "Matrix factorizations of homogeneous polynomials"). To illustrate this theorem, consider the polynomial $f=X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+X_4^2$. Clearly, this does not factor into linear factors in $R$. But in $\operatorname{Mat}_4(R)$ we have $$f.I_4=\begin{pmatrix} X_1&-X_2&X_3&X_4\\X_2&X_1&-X_4&X_3\\-X_3&X_4&X_1&X_2\\-X_4&-X_3&-X_2&X_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} X_1&X_2&-X_3&-X_4\\-X_2&X_1&X_4&-X_3\\X_3&-X_4&X_1&-X_2\\X_4&X_3&X_2&X_1\end{pmatrix}.$$ where $I_4$ is a $4\times 4$ identity matrix.
The theorem is that if $f$ has degree $d$ then it factorises as a product of $d$ linear factors in a suitable size matrix ring over $R$. One consequence of this is that some power of $f$ is the determinant of a matrix whose entries are homogeneous linear polynomials (or zero).
Matrix factorisations come from the theory of maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules over hypersurfaces. I believe the idea originates in the work of David Eisenbud, but there were probably others involved too.

That sure is a remarkable result!

And not widely enough known.

Is there a nice way of interpreting this result geometrically?
